# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils

Tags: java, sqoop, apache-commons-lang

Given below is the error. I have added the apache.org.common.lang jar still am getting this . am having these .JARs in my lib folder am is missing on any?

- ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar
- ant-eclipse-1.0-jvm1.2.jar
- avro-1.8.1.jar
- mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar
- org.apache.commons.lang-2.6.jar
- sqljdbc4-chs-4.0.2206.100.jar

```
h-user@h-primary:~/sqoop-1.4.7/lib$ sqoop eval --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/HADOOP_BANK_DATA_POC --username root --password xxxxxxxxx --query 'select * from E_INFO'
Warning: /home/h-user/sqoop-1.4.7/../hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
Warning: /home/h-user/sqoop-1.4.7/../hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: /home/h-user/sqoop-1.4.7/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
Warning: /home/h-user/sqoop-1.4.7/../zookeeper does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of your Zookeeper installation.
/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2366: HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.SQOOP.SQOOP_USER: invalid variable name
/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2461: HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.SQOOP.SQOOP_OPTS: invalid variable name
2022-12-24 16:23:55,026 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.7
2022-12-24 16:23:55,121 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
2022-12-24 16:23:55,314 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.initOptionDefaults(MySQLManager.java:73)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.<init>(SqlManager.java:89)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.<init>(SqlManager.java:33)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.<init>(GenericJdbcManager.java:51)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.<init>(GenericJdbcManager.java:30)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.CatalogQueryManager.<init>(CatalogQueryManager.java:46)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.CatalogQueryManager.<init>(CatalogQueryManager.java:31)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.InformationSchemaManager.<init>(InformationSchemaManager.java:38)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.InformationSchemaManager.<init>(InformationSchemaManager.java:31)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.<init>(MySQLManager.java:65)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory.accept(DefaultManagerFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.sqoop.ConnFactory.getManager(ConnFactory.java:184)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool.init(BaseSqoopTool.java:272)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.EvalSqlTool.run(EvalSqlTool.java:56)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 20 more
```